# Ruby and/or python: write telnetdata to file

Tags: ruby, python-3.x, telnet, telnetlib

i have a telnet-server running here (from a vendor) which is implemented in a barcode reader. to get the data, i simply need to connect to the telnetserver port 23 with my telnetclient from commandline.

What i want to do is doing this with ruby or python and write the output to a file.

so whats work until now:
i can connect to the telnet-server.

```
import sys
import telnetlib

tn = telnetlib.Telnet("10.0.0.138")
tn.close
output = tn.read_all()

# write to a file
with open("logging.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(output)

# Check that the file wrote correctly.
with open("logging.txt", "rb") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

What is not working:
writing the output from the telnetserver to a textfile. 
it doesnt matter for me if i do it with python or ruby, both languages are fine.
my codesample is python here. just for trying.

thanks for reading.

Comment: does the variable named "output" contain any data? did you try printing to stdout first? also, how come there's a call to "tn.close", and after that a "read_all", does not make sense to read a closed connection, you may want to move the "close" call after the "read_all"...

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7122064/125816

Comment: i added print(output) to the script and removed the tn.close completly. no output on screen.

Comment: Don't you normally need to *send* text in a telnet session to get text back? Even if it's just a bare newline? You can test this on the command line with your `telnet` command.